# Program that wont uninstall

Tags: windows-7, malware, uninstall

I got a program in some Chinese language, which I can't uninstall or kill it's process. Its name is 360 safe and another one Lenovo.

I tried to activate permission for them and I still get the message that I don't have the permission to get full control on it.

I don't know how to uninstall it from the app because it's in Chinese. I tried uninstaller programs, and setting permissions.

In control panel, it opens the app probably to uninstall it but I can't understand it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to [perform a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=uninstall+360safe). It isn't really a virus but it's a malware. It has been famous in China for a decade for it's malice.